# Summing three values of one column and inserting it in another column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table like this :

```
(ID)---(count)----(SumCount)
```

I have three rows (three count) for each ID, I want to sum them and insert them in `sumCount` grouped by their IDs.

My ideal result is one row for each ID and the SumCount for each of them.

Do I have to join the table to itself?

```
Update Mytable
set sumCount = (select sum(count) as SumCount from Mytable group by ID)
```

The problem is: it does not gives just one value and I get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update Yourtable
set sumCount=z.SumCount
From (select ID, sum(count) as SumCount 
      from Yourtable 
      groub by ID
     )z
where YourTable.Id = Z.ID
```

Comment: that's correct, but i dont know why the z alias does not contain id column. i get this error : Invalid column name 'ID'. it also underlined the last line Z.ID meaning z alias does not have ID column!!! but it gives SumCount as recommend

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I forget to add ID on my query.

Answer (score 1):

i think this worked correctly.
try and response

```
Update Mytable M1
  set sumCount=(select sum(count) from Mytable M2 WHERE M1.ID=M2.ID)
```